# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails when retrieving the maximum value of a field in MySQL database using Eclipse

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, eclipse

I am trying to retrieve the maximum value of the Experiment ID field from the Experiments table, adapted from [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319252/set-mysql-max-value-to-java-variable); however, there appears to be some syntax errors in my code, more specifically at the SELECT MAX - AS - FROM line:

```
public int returnExperimentNo() {
    int maxID = 0;
    Connection con = con();
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT MAX(Experiment ID) AS max_id FROM Experiments";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            maxID = rs.getInt("max_id");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    return maxID;   
}
```

I have tried putting Experiment ID in quotation mark (“), apostrophe (‘) and backtick (`); however, none of these worked. This is the error I got when Experiment ID is wrapped in backticks (the database is relational and Experiment ID is a foreign key used in the Logs table):

> Error: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (stockcontrolsystem.logs, CONSTRAINT logs_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (Experiment ID) REFERENCES Experiments (Experiment ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

[UPDATE] I have also tried adapting the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120482/foreign-key-problem-in-jdbc) to disable foreign keys check and enable it again after the operations have been carried out; however, the following code still has the same error as above:

```
public int returnExperimentNo() {
    int maxID = 0;
    Connection con = con();
    
    try {
        /**
         * Temporary disable foreign keys check to perform operations that would fail if these checks were enabled
         */
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT MAX(`Experiment ID`) AS max_id FROM Experiments";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            maxID = rs.getInt("max_id");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    
    try {
        /**
         * Enable foreign keys check
         */
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return maxID;
}
```

Since I’m still new to MySQL, can someone help me correct this? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There's a syntax error at the String sql = "SELECT MAX(Experiment ID) AS max_id FROM Experiments"; line

Comment: Your column name contains a space. You will definitely need to wrap it in backticks. If your code still doesn't work then there's something else wrong. Add the back ticks and post the error message you then get, if you get one.

Comment: This is the error I got when Experiment ID is wrapped in backticks (the database is relational and Experiment ID is a foreign key used in the Logs table): Error: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (stockcontrolsystem.logs, CONSTRAINT logs_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (Experiment ID) REFERENCES Experiments (Experiment ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)