# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (error still appeared after disabling foreign keys check)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, eclipse

I am trying to retrieve the maximum value of the Experiment ID field from the Experiments table in my database using Eclipse, adapted from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319252/set-mysql-max-value-to-java-variable). Because this is a relational database and Experiment ID is a foreign key also present in another table (Logs), I have followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120482/foreign-key-problem-in-jdbc) and attempted to disable foreign keys check in MySQL, enabling it again after the operations have been carried out to perform operations that would fail if these checks were enabled:

```
/**
 * Return max experiment number in the database 
 */
public int returnExperimentNo() {
    int maxID = 0;
    Connection con = con();
    
    try {
        /**
         * Temporary disable foreign keys check to perform operations that would fail if these checks were enabled
         */
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT MAX(`Experiment ID`) AS max_id FROM Experiments";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            maxID = rs.getInt("max_id");
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    
    try {
        /**
         * Enable foreign keys check
         */
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return maxID;
}
```

However, I still received the same error message as when the foreign keys check was enabled, saying:

> Error: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`stockcontrolsystem`.`logs`, CONSTRAINT `logs_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Experiment ID`) REFERENCES `Experiments` (`Experiment ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

There's also a new error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Since this is the final step in getting my program to function properly and I’m still unfamiliar with MySQL, can someone help me correct this? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You have no queries which alters data. So the errror message is generated by `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1`. Your tables contains inconsistent data. Fix this problem.

Comment: Since this is my first time using MySQL, I'm still uncertain on how to best correct this error. If possible, could someone make direct adjustments to my code? (your help would be greatly appreciated!)